# com.facebook.sdk error 2 when trying to reauthorize with different publish permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

When my app tries to invite people on the user's friends list, it checks for permissions on the active session. If those either of the permissions aren't found, it calls reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions.

The code in question is below:

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound || [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"user_photos"] == NSNotFound ) {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FacebookLogin"];
    [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"user_photos", nil]
           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
                            {
                                if (error)
                                {
                                    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can not get permission"
                                                                                    message:error.localizedFailureReason
                                                                                   delegate:self
                                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                    [alert show];
                                    [alert release];
                                    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FacebookLogin"];
                                }
                                else {
                                    if([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 0)
                                    {
                                        [self postFeedWithPermission:friendList];
                                    }
                                    else if ([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 1)
                                    {
                                        [self postPhotoWithPermission:friendList];
                                    }
                                    else if([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 2){
                                        [self postFeedDialog:friendList];
                                    }

                                }
                            }];
}

else
{
    if([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 0) {
        [self postFeedWithPermission:friendList];
    }
    else if ([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 1) {
        [self postPhotoWithPermission:friendList];
    }
    else if([[SocialNetworkingData getInstance] getFBDisplayType] == 2){
        [self postFeedDialog:friendList];
    }
}
```

No matter what, the completion handler receives an Error 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your app is authorized in settings>Facebook ^_^

Comment: Heh, yeah, it ended up being an issue with the account I was using specifically.